# Can't set header after they sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

***My code:***

```
function tokenReceived(response, error, token) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Access token error: ", error.message);
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write('<p>ERROR: ' + error + '</p>');
    response.end();
  }
  else {
 var cookies = ['node-tutorial-token=' + token.token.access_token + ';Max-Age=3600',
                   'node-tutorial-email=xxxx@xxx.xx;Max-Age=3600'];
                   console.log("cookies: ", cookies);
    response.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookies);
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write('<p>Access token saved in cookie.</p>');
    response.end();
  }
}
```

***My error:***

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
>       at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:344:11)
>       at tokenReceived (D:\node-tutorial\index.js:47:14)
>       at D:\node-tutorial\authHelper.js:41:9
>       at tryCatcher (D:\node-tutorial\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\util.js:26:23)
>       at Promise.successAdapter (D:\node-tutorial\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\nodeify.js:23:30)
>       at Promise._settlePromiseAt (D:\node-tutorial\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:579:21)
>       at Promise._settlePromises (D:\node-tutorial\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:697:14)
>       at Async._drainQueue (D:\node-tutorial\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:123:16)
>       at Async._drainQueues (D:\node-tutorial\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:133:10)
>       at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (D:\node-tutorial\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:15:14)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)

Comment: are we in the error or in the success case?

Comment: @RolandStarke i'm in the success case

Comment: ah! setHeader vs writeHead case again, what is node version used here?

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon `D:\node-tutorial>node --version
v5.4.1`

Comment: got it, see my answer and give it a try

Comment: i have the same issue,with two res.send() method in my code

Comment: @arjunkori you can also try the solution give in my answer, also update if it works for you too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response.setHeader` is only to set a singular header.

`response.writeHead` is to set multiple headers.

Try this way:

```
   response.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "text/html",
        "Set-Cookie": cookies
    });
```

Comment: could someone explain why this workst but OP's approatch dosn't?
nodejs has an example with `.setHeader` and `.writeHead`. See: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value

Comment: @RolandStarke you can try possible combinations, sometime when you are badly stuck you just seek the solution that just works

Answer (score 1):

Both `response.setHeader()` and `response.writeHead()` write (and commit) headers.

Your should either do

```
response.statusCode = 200;
response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
response.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookies);
```

Or

```
response.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/html',
    'Set-Cookie': cookies
});
```

Comment: `TypeError: response.status is not a function`

Answer (score -2):

This issues is beacuse you sent response two times(the first time with writeHead and second time with write). Try to use response.status(200).send(data)

Comment: it's in `if` condition is normal i write this two times

Comment: for modifying header use response.setHeader('access_token', token) and after that use response.status(200).send(data)